Flow rate of two sump pumps using a single 1.5-inch ABS pipe
I have two main sump pumps inside the same sump pit:

Liberty 297 ↗ (3/4 hp - 78
GPM)
Liberty 257 ↗ (1/3 hp - 47 GPM).

Each pump discharges through a 1.5-inch pipe. I plan to connect them using a Y-shaped connector to a single 1.5-inch discharge pipe that leads outside the house. Additionally, I have installed a back-water flow valve for each pump separately before they connect to the Y connector.
Can an IPEX Cell Core 1.5-inch ABS Pipe ↗ handle the combined flow rate of both pumps operating simultaneously during flooding or heavy rain?

so work out the speed of the flow in the pipe for each pump - separately and together. about 7m/s is a realistic maximum.

max flow is 80gpm
